# gdb unable to break on lstat call

Tags: php, c, debugging, gdb

I'm debugging PHP 5.2.9 and everything works fine, but today during debugging I see that gdb don't stop when I set:

```
(gdb) break lstat
```

the breakpoint is in the list

```
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x00002aaaaf810ea0
```

but, as written before, during execution gdb don't stop when lstat function is called.
Note that I'm sure that lstat is called by PHP engine because I can see the call using strace.

Please help me, what's wrong with gdb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set catchpoint on lstat syscall

```
(gdb) catch syscall lstat
Catchpoint 1 (syscall 'lstat' [107])
(gdb)
```

You will need gdb 7.0 or above

Answer (score 0):

`strace` is showing you that PHP is calling the system call `lstat`, however your breakpoint is actually on the library function `lstat()`.  It's possible that it's a different library call that is directly calling the `lstat` system call.

What does `ltrace` show?